# iMac won't read DVD-R and DVD+R

Tags: imac, optical-drive, dvd

I have a couple of TDK DVD-R and Maxell DVD+R that I have used to store photographs on. The DVDs are about 12 to 13 years old, but I have tried reading a few on a Windows PC and so far all could be read without error.

When I insert one of the DVD-R into my 2010 iMac running macOS 10.13.6, the computer futilely attempts to read the DVD only to eject it after a while. This is the same for all DVD-Rs. When I insert one of the DVD+R, my iMac tells me that I have inserted an empty medium and asks me whether I want to burn data on it. This is the same for all DVD+R.

The iMac does have trouble reading newer audio and video DVDs, but it faithfully reads all my old audio DVDs. I therefore think that there is nothing wrong with the drive, like dirt on the lense, but a compatibility problem with the software trying to read the DVDs.

What can I do?

Comment: It is more likely that the drive is dying. And, hate to say it, but depending on how they are stored and what brand of DVD you bought they *could* all have failed. Less likely but possible. Buy a Mac compatible DVD drive from a company with a liberal return policy, or find a safe way to borrow (or use...) a Mac from a friend.

Comment: Some drives never liked +/- R discs even if they wrote it themselves. I still have two external drives that I use, infrequently now, but one does up to blueray the other is earlier... so the drive on the iMac does some and the externals catch the others. After all 3 then I chuck the dvd...

Comment: Amazon has an inexpensive [CD/DVD reader/writer](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07MJW5BXZ/) with free returns if you're an Amazon Prime member. If your DVDs can't be read, you can at least return the drive.

Comment: If you have a computer which can read the DVDs: get an external USB storage device, connect it to the computer which can read the DVDs and copy all DVDs to that device.